# access to nested array in tabular

Tags: tabulator

i have a json array with nested arrays. How can I access them in tabulator

the array contains a list of flights

```
data = [
 flights
  flights.price
  flights.departure // departure // Frankfurt
  flights.arrival // final destination // Houston
  flights .... etc
  flights.route
   flights.route[0].from  // flight #1 Frankfurt
   flights.route[0].to    // flight #1 Washington
   flights.route[1].from  // flight #2 Washington
   flights.route[1].to    // flight #2 Houston
 ....
 ]
```

How can i access the route[X].from and list it as value in Tabulator?
I already have read about nested fields (e.g user.name), but how can you access arrays if they have no names but only numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Use [data tree](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/tree) for nested data

```
data:tableDataNested,
    dataTree:true,
```